# PHP Xpath string a XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Me asalta una duda. Yo sé que puedo transformar un string como:

```
<nodo1><nodo_1_hijo></nodo_1_hijo></nodo>
```

A xml con SimpleXMLElement.

Pero, ¿será posible transformar un xpath a xml como el siguiente?:

```
//nodo1/nodo_1_hijo
```

¿Y que quede tal como el ejemplo de más arriba?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarnos un poco más qué duda tienes? ¿Quieres escribir un programa en PHP para generar un documento en formato XML de una expresión XPath como `//nodo1/nodo_1_hijo`? ¿Cúal es tu duda con este XPath, el uso de `//` al principio? ¿O el uso de XPath con SimpleXMLElement?

Comment: No existe ninguna función que haga el trabajo directo, pero se podría implementar un conversor sencillo en PHP (incrementándose la complejidad conforme aumentes la funcionalidad). ¿Deseas el ejemplo de implementación o que te confirmemos que sí es posible?

Comment: ¿Te solucionó tus dudas alguna respuesta? Si es así agradecería que marcaras aquella que lo hizo como correcta. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El [lenguaje de caminos XML (`Xpath`)](http://www.sidar.org/recur/desdi/traduc/es/xml/xpath.html) fue creado para [facilitar la búsqueda de elementos dentro de un árbol XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction):

> The primary purpose of XPath is to address parts of an **XML document**
>
> El objetivo principal de XPath es acceder a partes de un **documento
>   XML**

Por lo que no es aconsejable usar una ruta `xpath` como descripción de la estructura de un documento `XML`. Para eso se usan los [DTD](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definici%C3%B3n_de_tipo_de_documento).

Si quieres generar un `XML` básico a partir de una ruta básica `xpath` puedes usar este pequeño trozo de código:

```
<pre><?php
function agregar_xml_desde_xpath($xpath, $dom) {
    $elementos = explode('/', $xpath);
    $actual = $dom;
    foreach ($elementos as $elemento) {
        if (!empty($elemento)) {
            $nuevo = $dom->createElement($elemento);
            $actual->appendChild($nuevo);
            $actual = $nuevo;
        }
    }
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
agregar_xml_desde_xpath('//nodo1/nodo_1_hijo', $dom);
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML(null, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG));
?><pre>
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nodo1><nodo_1_hijo></nodo_1_hijo></nodo1>
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que es una implementación muy sencilla que sólo obtiene el árbol de nodos. Para rutas más complejas (usando atributos, funciones, etc) la implementación podría volverse compleja.

Answer (score 0):

Es bastante fácil con la función `xpath` que tiene SimpleXMLElement

Sería tal que así:

```
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$reg = $obj->xpath('//nodo1/nodo_1_hijo');
echo $reg[0]->saveXML();
```

En $xml deberías tener el string del XML. Éste debería ser correcto, en tu caso ahora mismo no lo es, ya que abres como nodo1, pero cierras como nodo. De todas formas el propio PHP te avisará de esos errores.

En mi código como verás paso a XML sólo el **primer registro** que coincida con el XPath que has indicado. Si quisieras sacar todas las coincidencias deberías de utilizar un `foreach`.

Comment: Me temo que esto no soluciona la transformación de una ruta `xpath` en `xml` que solicita el usuario.

Comment: Ok, viendo tu código y releyendo la pregunta lo entiendo ahora.

Comment: No pasa nada, sólo te quería avisar. A todos nos pasa este tipo de cosas ;)